# Load Content in div without refreshing whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flask

I am creating a small webapp in flask,where I have a sidebar navigation which consist of all question.
When I click on question,respective question page is rendered in right section.
But,the question which is clicked,is not selected and navigate to the top.

How, I can keep the question which is clicked selected and on focus?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'montserrat';
    background: #e3e9f7;
}

.logo {
    padding: 20px;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 260px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #2b2626;
    max-height: 100vh;
        overflow-y: auto;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
}


nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'montserrat';
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 25px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

nav ul li a:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #e3e9f7;
    border-radius: 40px 0 0 40px;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all 1s;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #2b2626;
}

nav ul li a:hover:before {
    width: 95%;
}


.wrapper {
    margin-left: 260px;

}

.section {
    display: grid;
    top: 60px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;

}


.box-area h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#myBtn {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 200px;
    z-index: 99;
    font-size: 8px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

nav ul#my-ul {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
   
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script>
    function scrollToTop() {
            const el = document.getElementById("my-ul");
            el.scrollTop = 0;
        }
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">

</head>

<nav id="my-div">
    <ul  id="my-ul">
        <li class="logo"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/E26Pj54.png"></li>
        <li><a href="{{url_for('get_live')}}"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp; Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{url_for('get_live')}}"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>&nbsp; Book</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{url_for('get_live')}}"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>&nbsp; Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{url_for('get_live')}}"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>&nbsp; Pictures</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{url_for('get_live')}}"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp; Contact</a></li>

             
                <li><a href="{{url_for('get_live')}}"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>&nbsp; Book</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{url_for('get_live')}}"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>&nbsp; Users</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{url_for('get_live')}}"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>&nbsp; Pictures</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{url_for('get_live')}}"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp; Contact</a></li>


                     
                        <li><a href="{{url_for('get_live')}}"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>&nbsp; Book</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{url_for('get_live')}}"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>&nbsp; Users</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{url_for('get_live')}}"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>&nbsp; Pictures</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{url_for('get_live')}}"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp; Contact</a></li>

                             
                     
    </ul>

   
</nav>



<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="box-area">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
              
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<button id="myBtn" onclick="scrollToTop()">Back To Top Question</button>
 
</script>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below syntax.

```
function scrollToTop() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: That will scroll all the way to top.How,can I scroll to the question(li item) which was clicked after page refreshes on click?